# How do i extract the contents of a numpy array to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I have the following numpy array..

```
In[48]: idx
Out[48]: (array([223, 226, 445, 494, 546, 696, 702, 713, 725, 749], dtype=int64),)
```

Can anyone tell me how I convert this into a list or another dataframe? I've tried the tolist() function but it doesn't work, it gives the error ''tuple' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: `idx` is not a NumPy array, it's a tuple containing a NumPy array. So: `idx[0].tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `idx[0].tolist()`, your array is encapsulated in a tuple.